# Protect only one VBA macro with password

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with VBA script. In this script, I have a code that causes the 'save as' function to be disabled. I would like to protect this small piece of code with a password.... Is this possible? Because my co-users would also need to get into that Visual Basic Editor for other projects, so only a few lines of code need to be protected with a password.

IS it possible?

Comment: I haven't tried anything... only the code to lock the save as button

Comment: One way to control the access to a macro is by checking the user with ``environ("Username")``.

Comment: Beware that VBA project passwords can be removed, so the code that you want to protect is not as secure as you want it to be.

Comment: As far as I know, that's simply not possible. As you've clearly already worked out, you can password protect access to the project, but that's it. FWIW, off hand, I can't think of a reason for wanting to do this. If others are trusted with the code, then can't you just agree what's be changed or not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.